# Can I take coffee that has been used and resealed?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tsa, hawaii

I am going to Honolulu and then travel to a few places in America. Are you allowed to take coffee and use it at each destination, instead of having to buy some at each place?

Comment: "used" coffee would generally mean grounds that had been used to make a drink. I think you mean "opened".

Answer (score 6):

It is [fine to take coffee beans or grounds on a plane](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/coffee-beans-or-ground), though [new TSA rules](https://www.cnn.com/2018/06/20/politics/tsa-powder-carry-on-bags/index.html) mean that containers of 12oz or more of powder in carry-on bags may receive more scrutiny. Keeping grounds in their original container, or placing them in checked luggage, may be helpful in this regard. Consider double-bagging so it doesn't spill or stink up your bag.

If you're bringing the coffee in from out of the country, [CBP states](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/335/~/importing-coffee%2C-tea-or-spices-for-personal-use) that "There are no restrictions on the importation of coffee, tea or spices for personal use, although they may be subject to Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service (APHIS) and Food and Drug Administration (FDA) inspections if a Customs and Border Protection (CBP) Officer suspects contamination or insect infestation of the product."

You'll also go through a [USDA agricultural screening](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/travelers-int/ct_hawaiian_products) when leaving Hawaii for the US mainland. Fresh coffee berries are not allowed in this case, but commercially roaster coffee should be ok after you've shown them to the inspector.

Coffee, both by the cup and in bean/ground form, is extremely available throughout the US, so it's not a particular burden to buy it in the US either.